# How can I sort by multiple columns in R if the column names are stored in a vector?

Tags: r, sorting

So I am trying to tidy up some data, and want to arrange my table based on several columns. So if I have a table

```
a <- (1:5)
b <- (6:10)
c <- (11:15)
d <- (16:20)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c,d))
```

I need to sort by column a, then by column b, but I have to take these values from a vector.

```
x <- c(a,b)
```

Currently I am using order or arrange and inserting the column names manually, so something like:

```
df <- arrange(df, a, b)
```

But ideally I would not have to insert them manually, and be able to take them from a vector, which might change depending on certain other parameters.

I tried something like

```
df <- df[,with(df, order(x))]
```

Or

```
df <- df[order(df[,1:2]),]
```

But it keeps messing up the table. The data frame I'm working with is quite big, and the columns might differ depending on a circumstance, so I want to know if it is possible inserting them manually each time.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Comment: df and x have different lengths, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to have a `vector` of column names

```
x <- names(df)[1:2]
```

and then use `arrange_`

```
df %>%
   arrange_(x)
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about the arrange_ functionality.